# Does Tearing and Proven apply to Righteous Fury?

Tags: weapons, dark-heresy-1e

Let's say I hit a Righteous Fury with a weapon that has Proven (3). Does the Righteous Fury die also count as having Proven (3)? Alternatively, if the weapon had Tearing, would I roll two dice for Righteous Fury and drop the lowest?